# AJAX/PHP: Issue with google maps retrieving data from my code

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, google-maps-markers

I am currently following this guide at Google developers.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=en-EN#createmap

I am adding a map on my website with geocoded entries. Each entry into the table is a business. Each entry/business currently has a field/column for

(`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`, `url`)

Screenshot Here http://postimg.org/image/3z8kcwq4b/

I was able to add the `url` field and it be displayed properly on the map markers. I need to be able to also add two more fields. 1 for 'phonenumber' and one for 'description.

the purpose of the above entries into the database is that when they click a marker on the map of an entry/business it will display information about that business. I can't get it to show this information when clicked. The code that I believe to be relevant to my issue is below.

here is the code I currently have.

Main Page:

```
  var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
  var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
  var url = markers[i].getAttribute("url");
  var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
  var html = '<a href="' + url + '">' + name + '</a> <br/>' + address + ' <br/>' ;
```

phpsqlajax_genxml2.php

```
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo 'url="' . $row['url'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
```

I need to be able to add more info into the database so i can make the map call it. I would like for it to display a phone number and description when they click the map marker for that business.

(the above code pulls data from the tables on the database and displays the url of the business, the name of it, it's long/lat-geocoded, and it's address.)

I have been able to completely add this into my site except for this. Last thing i'm stuck on.

Comment: I am not clear as to how the PHP code relates to the javascript code in your example.

Comment: If you read the article above it will show you. Atleast I think. To much code to copy paste, sorry.

Comment: I am still not following.  What does the code shown for `phpsqlajax_genxml2.php` have to do with the code shown for `Main Page`?

Comment: It's from the files shown in the dev article above.

Comment: I assumed it was related or i needed to edit it as well when adding in new fields.

Comment: I don;t know I am not going to read the whole article as it is not going to tell me specifically what problem you are having.  You haven't narrowed it down at all.  Is the problem in retrieving data from a database? in echoing the data out in PHP? in accessing the PHP data via javascript? in displaying the data using javascript?  I don't know what the actual problem is.

Comment: Yeah i see. Let me re word the question about. Will take me a second.

Comment: I've edited my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to ffix this issue like this

```
  var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
  var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
  var url = markers[i].getAttribute("url");
  var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
  var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
  var desc = markers[i].getAttribute("desc");
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
  var html = '<a href="' + url + '">' + name + '</a> <br/>' + address + '<br />Phone Number: ' + phone + '<br />' + desc + '<br />';
```

---

```
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo 'phone="' . $row['phone'] . '" ';
  echo 'desc="' . $row['desc'] . '" ';
  echo 'url="' . $row['url'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
```